# bigSlide.js - off-screen slide panel navigation

Tags: jquery, mobile, nav, sliding, responsive-slides

I'm using the excellent bigSlide.js off-screen slide panel navigation plugin (link below). I'm getting an intermittent issue when you scroll up and down the page on a mobile device (iPhone 5) the menu pops out, I can't work out what would be triggering this and as I say it seems pretty random without any real pattern to it. Apologies I can't diagnose this any further at the moment but there is a link below if you wanted to try and replicate the issue. Has anyone come across any similar issues using this plugin? I have tried contacting the plugin author for ideas but no response as of yet.

The plugin in action
http://isodo3d.atelierhq.com/

bigSlide.js
http://ascott1.github.io/bigSlide.js/

I'm sure it must be something to do with the following CSS being triggered

```
.panel {
    position: fixed;
    left: -15.625em; /*left or right and the width of your navigation panel*/
    width: 15.625em; /*should match the above value*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think 
the menu pops out because the menu position is not relative .
so you can fix the position and wrap the menu .

http://ascott1.github.io/bigSlide.js/

```
.wrap { 
    position: relative; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response... I have implemented the CSS a per the documentation... .wrap is positioned relative and #menu is taken care of via the plugin with position fixed.